# Getting params value in rails create method from controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My code has send s

```
    <% url = url_for(:controller => 'boxelements', :action => 'new', :project_id => @project.id, :author_id => User.current.id)  %>
    <%= link_to "Upload New File",url %>
```

from new method I can get the param values

```
    def new
      @boxelement = Boxelement.new
      puts params[:project_id]
      puts params[:author_id]
    end
```

Here is how I send this value as a form input

```
    <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value =>project_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :author_id, :value =>User.current.id %>
```

I need to access those value from create method of the controller

```
    def create
      @boxelement = Boxelement.new(params[:boxelement])

      if @boxelement.save
        puts params[:project_id] 
        puts params[:author_id]
      end
    end
```

This code shows nothing when they are in create method of controller.

```
    puts params[:project_id]
    puts params[:author_id]
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this line I can assume you want to access params of :boxelement

```
     @boxelement = Boxelement.new(params[:boxelement])
```

use the following line in order to access the params value.

```
 puts params[:boxelement][:project_id] 
 puts params[:boxelement][:author_id]
```